How to change the text value of the build number and windows version on the bottom right of a Windows 11 screen?
How to change the text value of the place where the build number and windows version on the bottom right of a Windows 11 screen is shown?
Via powershell or another scripting option.
Thanks

upgrade windows? Why do you want to put fake information there?

You cannot change it. If you don’t want the version displayed, reinstall Windows, and avoid the Insider Preview builds. You should only install Windows 11 24H2 or Windows 10 22H2

Lol, I have a valid Windows 11 box. Just want to know if it's possible to customize the message that is displayed there. I want to put my own strings there, not the build number or windows version.

You can make a background screen with any text you want displayed. Have the text state you have an Atari 800XL, or it's running on El Capitan (https://www.hpe.com/us/en/newsroom/blog-post/2024/11/hpe-built-direct-liquid-cooled-supercomputers-top-november-2024-lists-of-fastest-and-most-energy-efficient-systems-in-the-world.html) using 1994 ANS Forth OS.

That's a pretty good workaround, might do that. Was looking for something more simple like a few lines of powershell to change some registry keys or something like that. But this could work. Thanks.
